# Not sure if I did the recursion right with the linked lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the longest string with recursion and while I get the right answer I'm not sure if my method IS recursion.  I have a linked list in my main that I need to fin the longest.  my String largest method is the "recursion"

```
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class MyLinkedList extends LinkedList<String> {
  public static String max="";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MyLinkedList myLinkedList = new MyLinkedList();
    myLinkedList.add("Sarah");
    myLinkedList.add("Barbara");
    myLinkedList.add("Tom");
    myLinkedList.add("George");
    String largest = myLinkedList.findLargestStarter();
    String largest1= largest( myLinkedList,0, 1);
    System.out.println("Largest "+largest1);
    System.out.println("max "+max);

}


public String findLargestStarter()
{
    //largest=max;
    return null;


}

public static  String largest(MyLinkedList myLinkedList, int lowerIndex, int upperIndex)
{
     if(lowerIndex == upperIndex)   //the size of the sublist                       // is 1
      max= myLinkedList.get(lowerIndex);
   else
   {
      max = largest(myLinkedList, lowerIndex + 1, upperIndex);
      if( myLinkedList.get(lowerIndex).length() >      myLinkedList.get(upperIndex).length())
          max= myLinkedList.get(lowerIndex);
      else
          max= myLinkedList.get(upperIndex);
   }
//   System.out.println(max);
     return max;
}
```

}

Comment: How about addind some comments in your code so that we understand what you are doing. Describe the algorithm you try to use. From what I see your code only looks into the first two elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not going line by line, your recursion method `largest` looks good as:

1. **Its calling itself** from else block. First behavior satisfied.
2. There is a termination condition on the top (**your if block**), where it doesn't call itself. Second behavior satisfied.

I don't understand why you have put logic below the call to `largest` method in `else` block. Hope you understand that better.

Comment: should the top (your if block) call itself?

Comment: No. That is the termination criteria when you have reached to the end and found your max for that particular cycle of the recursion call. This max is ultimately being return from the function to move the cycle backwards and complete your function. Please let me know, if you need more inputs. I will try to explain though a simple example.

Comment: Negative Voter: Please add some comment to help me understand the gap/issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are few small improvements you could make to look this program more readable and better overall:

- Eliminate usage of global static variable. Its really bad taste and point of recursive function that it should return answer as return parameter
- If you want to try to get recursion right, not create your own datastructures then use list from java.util package.

I've put together few lines which could be possible solution to your problem. Approach is just to reduce list each time it goes deeper until its empty:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FindTheLongest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Sarah", "Barbara", "Tom", "George" });
        System.out.println(findLongestString(list, list.get(0)));
    }

    private static String findLongestString(List<String> list, String longestString) {
        if (!list.isEmpty())
        {
            final List<String> nextList = list.subList(1, list.size());
            final String nextLongestString = longestString.length() > list.get(0).length() ? longestString : list.get(0);
            return findLongestString(nextList, nextLongestString);
        }
        return longestString;
    }
}
```

Please let me know of that what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Our goal is to exercise about recursion.

I appreciate more the answer of Yogendra Singh because it's more scholar.

The proposition of Petro Semeniuk works well but it's not the question.

AMHO reuse of LinkedList< T > is not a good choice.

To understand recursion, to touch its internal behavior, we have to develop a naive implementation of linked list with no import at all but java.lang and debug step by step its method.

I suggest a class like:

```
public class StringNode // no generics, it's not the goal
{
   public StringNode next;
   public String     text;

   public StringNode( String text )
   {
      this( text, null );
   }

   public StringNode( String text, StringNode next )
   {
      this.text = text;
      this.next = next;
   }

   public String getLongest()
   {
      String nextText = (( next == null ) ? "" : this.next.getLongest());
      return ( this.text.length() > nextText.length()) ? this.text : nextText;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      StringNode head = null;
      for( String text : new String[] { "Sarah", "Barbara", "Tom", "George" })
      {
         head = new StringNode( text, head );
      }
      System.err.println( head.getLongest());
   }
}
```

Performance note: the new operator is not directly called outside of main().